# Star rating is not working from left to right

Tags: html, css

I have star rating in HTML and CSS and it's working. But, the star is working backward, from right to left. I want it to work normal, from left to right. Please do suggest me a way. Thanks in advance.

The HTML code:

```
<th style="vertical-align:middle">Your Rating</th>

<td>
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" 
    onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" 
    onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" 
    onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" 
    onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" 
    onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
 <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="starRate" name="starRate" value="" readonly>
</td>
</tr>
```

The CSS

```
div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;

}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
float: center;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #444;
cursor:pointer;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
content: '\f005';
color: #FD4;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
color: #FE7;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }


label.star:before {
content: '\f006';
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Script myFunction

```
  <script>
      function myFunction(rating) {
      document.getElementById("starRate").value = rating;
  </script>
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMU8g.png)

Comment: Where is `myFunction`?

Comment: <script>
  function myFunction(rating) {
    document.getElementById("starRate").value = rating;
  }
 </script>

Comment: Please add the js function too.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the myFunction script. Thank you @dhruvtailor

Comment: @Arvina: Hi There ! When you say it is working from right to left.  I don't understand it fully. If you could simply share an output image with me. I will try to help :) Currently though CSS is applying correctly but your code doesn't give any value. You can put all you code on jsfiddle.com and share the link with me . I can  quickly work on that and help you out with this :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I have attached the image output above. If you view it, you can see that the last 3 star is checked. Meanwhile, the 2 star in the front is unchecked.

Comment: I have completed it in a most efficient way for you. Let me add my answer.

Comment: @Terry: Hey Bro !  Everything fine :) Is any one asking repeated questions my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Final Working Code.
I have not touched your HTML file. Keeping the same code and order of inputs I have resolved your problem.

You have a hidden rating input initially. In order to make it work, I have used javascript `setAttribute()` only once a star icon is clicked.

Have also used one function handler only instead of repeating function call in each of the inputs in the HTML itself, which is a bad coding practice. Have thus separated concerns. HTML file now contains only the HTML and Javascript takes care of logic part and function cals.

Code looks cleaner and is following **DRY Principle**.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/qBamGzm

```js
let starRate = document.querySelector("#starRate");
document.querySelectorAll(".star").forEach(input=>{
  input.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    starRate.value = e.target.value;
    starRate.setAttribute("type","text");
  })
})
```

```css
.inputsWrapper{
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
float: center;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #444;
cursor:pointer;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
content: '\f005';
color: #FD4;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
color: #FE7;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }


label.star:before {
content: '\f006';
font-family: FontAwesome;
}

#starRate{
 width:20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr> 
<th style="vertical-align:middle">Your Rating</th>

<td class="inputsWrapper">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" 
    />
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" 
    />
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" 
    />
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" 
    />
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" 
   />
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="starRate" name="starRate" readonly/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using radios for this, you could use javascript to apply a class to all of the other (lower valued stars).

```js
function myFunction(rating) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(cb => cb.classList.remove('highlight'))
  for (let i = Number(rating); i > 0; i--) {
    document.querySelector(`input[value="${i}"]`).classList.add('highlight')
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input+label:before {
  content: '\f005';
}

input.highlight+label:before {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-1"></label>

  <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-2"></label>

  <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-3"></label>

  <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-4"></label>

  <input id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-5"></label>

  <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="starRate" name="starRate" value="" readonly>
</td>
```

If using checkboxes, you could loop through all the lower valued inputs and make them checked.

```js
function myFunction(rating) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(cb => cb.checked = false)
  for (let i = Number(rating); i > 0; i--) {
    document.querySelector(`input[value="${i}"]`).checked = true
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input+label:before {
  content: '\f005';
}

input:checked+label:before {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input id="star-1" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-1"></label>

  <input id="star-2" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-2"></label>

  <input id="star-3" type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-3"></label>

  <input id="star-4" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-4"></label>

  <input id="star-5" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" />
  <label for="star-5"></label>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi, the code is good but I'm not getting the star shape instead it's in square shape. How can I work on it?

Comment: This code does not include the `font awesome` font.